# Ionic 2: is there any way to show tabs on a page that is not a child of the tabs?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have tabs that I would like to show on every page, but it appears that I can only show tabs on pages that are children of the tabs. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you got an answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

there are some discussion [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-hide-tabs/37998/30).

One of the solutions which I prefer is:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbar');
  if ( tabs !== null ) {
    Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
      tabs[ key ].style.transform = 'translateY(56px)';
    });
  } // end if
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbar');
  if ( tabs !== null ) {
    Object.keys(tabs).map((key) => {
      tabs[ key ].style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    });
  } // end if
}
```

What is does is, when some view is going to display, hide the tabs with `translateY(56px)`. And display them when going back.